# How to add to HTMLElement properly with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm running into two problems when trying to add methods to **HTMLElement** properly with **TypeScript**:

1. I'm not sure how to **add methods** to an existing class that I don't own (**without creating a new class** via "extends", so that I don't have to add annotations anywhere I am creating an HTMLElement).
2. I'm not sure if there's a *simpler* way to refer to "**this**" without explicitly noting the type via (this as HTMLElement).

Example:

```
let newProps = {
    tag: {
        get: function(): any {
            return (typeof (<unknown>this as HTMLElement).getAttribute('tagged') != 'undefined') //Any better way to handle this?
        },
        set: function(tagged: boolean) {
            if (tagged) {
                (<unknown>this as HTMLElement).removeAttribute('tagged'); 
            } else {
                (<unknown>this as HTMLElement).setAttribute('tagged', '');
            }
        },
    },
};
Object.defineProperties(HTMLElement.prototype, newProps); 

/* 
... define an HTMLElement as a button 
*/

//@ts-ignore
myButton.tag = true; //error: Property 'tag' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'  //How to add new method to HTMLElement without using "extends" to create a new class??
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It's considered a reeeeeeeeally bad practice to change hosted objects' prototypes. Why do you want that instead of simply a function that accepts an element as its argument?

Comment: Would just make for cleaner, simpler code if I could get/set simple properties on the button. Less verbose.

Comment: "Would just make for cleaner, simpler code" --- it won't be simpler: it's impossible to tell where that function comes from.

Comment: In what context? I'm writing the involved methods for my own use. Not sure I'm following the concern.

Comment: I am also wondering this. In order to add a custom method in HTMLElement, I want to extend it but it is an interface so If i extend it, i have to implement all of its methods which is not reasonable. I couldn't find what actually implements HTMLElement or other inherited HTMLElements. document.createElement() returns HTMLElement but it does not have a class. It must be due to the fact that javascript is a functional language and typescript is a superset of it. But it can be great if one could really implement oop inheritance in typescript. I would be happy if one could points at a direction.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add to the global `HTMLElement` interface.

## Working example

```
// Augment the global 
interface HTMLElement {
  tag: boolean
}


// Now no error 
declare const myButton: HTMLElement;
myButton.tag = true; // No error
```

## More

- [Modifying native types](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/lib.d.ts#modifying-native-types)

Comment: That works for new properties, however TypeScript now throws errors for native properties/methods such as removeAttribute():

(<unknown>this as HTMLElement).removeAttribute('disabled'); //TS: Property 'removeAttribute' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.